# Jquery get json data with number

Tags: jquery, json, nested

i have this Json:

```
"AMAZ": {
    "LOAS": {
        "1": "NAME1",
        "2": "NAME2"
    },
"BAG": {
    "ASLO": {
        "1": "NAME1",
        "2": "NAME2"
    }
```

im trying to get the NAME1 and NAME2 text.

I tried with:

```
var json = $.parseJSON($("#json").val());
var test = json.AMAZ.LOAS.'1';
alert(test);
```

but i get an error here:

```
var test = json.AMAZ.LOAS.'1';
```

i get Unexpected string '1'

How can i get the values?

Comment: that number is index to get index use `json.AMAZ.LOAS[1]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you json.parse, your "1"'s and "2"'s become the most inner values in your json, as well they become integers when parsed (I don't know why). you can use them in brackets:

```
var data = JSON.parse(`
  {"AMAZ": {"LOAS": {
        "1": "NAME1",
        "2": "NAME2"
    },
"BAG": {
    "ASLO": {
        "1": "NAME1",
        "2": "NAME2"
    }}}}`); 

// Try edit message

console.log(data)
console.log(data.AMAZ.LOAS[1])
```

hope this helps.

Comment: var myvariable = data.AMAZ.LOAS[1];

Comment: sorry, I just understood what you asked for.   `var id = 1` or `var id = 2`.  you can also loop through the data in a for loop.

Comment: Dont worry i did it yesterday. thanks for your help!! :)